spath3 rotations shrink paths
I am using spath3 to rotate a path, but it is shrinking.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[] (0,0) circle(1);
%%% This one works. %%%
\draw[-latex,spath/save=name] (0,0) -- (45:1);
%%% This one is shorter. %%%
\path[draw,-latex,red,spath/use={name,transform={rotate around={90:(spath cs:name 0)}}}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



cfr's diagnosis is completely correct: each arrow specification shortens the line so the second path is doubly-shortened. I recently added a key spath/arrow shortening to control whether an arrow does shorten a path which can be used to disable the second shortening (and so avoid having to guess magic numbers), but actually I think a cleaner way in this circumstance would be to define the path first without any shortening (and not draw it) and then draw two instances of it with arrows.
The following code illustrates both of those options.
\documentclass{standalone}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/721713/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[] (0,0) circle[radius=1]; % newer circle syntax
% This defines the path but doesn't render it
\path[spath/save=name] (0,0) -- (45:1);
% Draw it as-is with an arrow
    \draw[-{Latex[length=3.5pt]},spath/use=name];
% Draw it with an arrow and rotated
    \path[draw,-{Latex[length=3.5pt]},red,spath/use={name,transform={rotate around={90:(spath cs:name 0)}}}];
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
    \draw[-{Latex[length=3.5pt]},spath/save=name] (0,0)  -- (45:1);
% This time, when we use it, we disable the arrow shortening since that 
% has already been applied when the path was defined.
    \path[draw,-{Latex[length=3.5pt]},spath/arrow shortening=false,red,spath/use={name,transform={rotate around={90:(spath cs:name 0)}}}];
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Ref.: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/153642/discussion-between-cfr-and-andrew-stacey
The trouble is that the path is shortened to accommodate the arrow tip and it is the shortened version which is used as the basis for the second path. Since that has an arrow, too, it is itself shortened, so the fact that the same tip is used each time doesn't help.
You can compensate for the shortening by extending the path by the length of the arrow tip. The easiest way is to use the updated syntax provided by arrows.meta and specify the length of the tips manually. Since the default tips in arrows are considered deprecated, this is a good idea in any case.
For example,
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{spath3,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[] (0,0) circle(1);
    %%% This one works. %%%
    \draw[-{Latex[length=3.5pt]},spath/save=name] (0,0)  -- (45:1);
    %%% This one is the same length. %%%
    \path[draw,-{Latex[length=3.5pt]},shorten >=-3.5pt,red,spath/use={name,transform={rotate around={90:(spath cs:name 0)}}}];
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



is there a default length for arrow tips? Is it always 3.5pt?

@Jasper Sort of. It depends on the width of the path, though (and maybe the arrow tip) and whether it is double or not. 3.5pt isn't the default. I just tried a couple of values until it looked about right. You can see how the dimensions are calculated in the manual page 193 'The line width factors' if you want the gory details. (You'll see why I tried a couple of values until it looked about right!)

I see; so it's sort of like line breaking in display math - it's cleaner to do it yourself. Thank you for your help.

@Jasper I don't think it is cleaner. But there's nothing special about the defaults which are designed to be configurable, so there's really no particular reason to calculate it ;). But if, say, you wanted to make the line width configurable, there'd be a reason to calculate it and it would be worth the effort.

Ack! The room's now frozen so I can't reply to your last message there. Sorry - I get short spans where I can respond to stuff, and then long gaps where I get busy with other things.

@AndrewStacey Not a problem. You can ask for a room to be unfrozen, but I don't know why they don't let people unfreeze them themselves. :-) Thanks for updating me.

@Jasper Please accept Andrew's answer rather than mine.
